# Different Columns for Each Row in HBase?

Tags: hadoop, time-series, hbase

In my HBase table, each row may be have different columns than other rows. For example;

```
ROW                       COLUMN
1-1040                    cf:s1
1-1040                    cf:s2
1-1043                    cf:s2
2-1040                    cf:s5
2-1045                    cf:s99
3-1040                    cf:s75
3-1042                    cf:s135
```

As seen above, each row has different columns than other rows. So, when I run scan query like this;

> scan 'tb', {COLUMNS=>'cf:s2', STARTROW=>'1-1040', ENDROW=>'1-1044'}

I want to get **cf:s2** values using above query. But, does any performance issue occur due to each row has different columns?

**Another option;**

```
ROW                       COLUMN
1-1040-s1                 cf:value
1-1040-s2                 cf:value
1-1043-s2                 cf:value
2-1040-s5                 cf:value
2-1045-s99                cf:value
3-1040-s75                cf:value
3-1042-s135               cf:value
```

In this option, when I want to get **s2** values between 1-1040 and 1-1044, I am running this query for this;

> scan 'tb', {STARTROW=>'1-1040s2', ENDROW=>'1-1044', FILTER=>"RowFilter(=, 'substring:s2')"}

When I want to get **s2** values, which option is better in read performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HBase stores all records for a given column family in the same file, and so the scan has to run over all key-value pairs, even if you apply a filter. This is true of both ways you suggest for storing the data.

For optimal performance of this specific scan, you should consider storing your `s2` data in a different column family. Under-the-hood, HBase will store your data in the following way:

One file:

```
1-1040                    cf1:s1
2-1040                    cf1:s5
2-1045                    cf1:s99
3-1040                    cf1:s75
3-1042                    cf1:s135
```

Another file:

```
1-1040                    cf2:s2
1-1043                    cf2:s2
```

Then you can run a scan over just `cf2`, and HBase will only read data containing `s2`, making the operation much faster.

```
scan 'tb', {COLUMNS => 'cf2', STARTROW=>'1-1040s2', ENDROW=>'1-1044'}
```

Considerations:

- It's recommended to only have two or three column families per table, so you shouldn't implement this if you want to run this query for `s5`, `s75` etc. In this case, your composite rowkey option is better as HBase only need look at the rowkey, and not column qualifiers.
- It depends on exactly which queries you'll be running, and how often you'll be running them. This is the fastest way for you to get values associated with `s2`, but might not be fastest for other queries.

Comment: In fact, I wonder that does any performance issue occur due to each row(for different ids) have different columns when I scan table. Because, maybe 1000+ different columns in the same column family will be. But each row will be have maximum 30 columns. I know that Column or Row filtering will cause a performance issue. But I don't know that what happens if there's too much column in the background. So, I am looking whether can I put these values(s1,s2, s55 etc) to rowKey.

Comment: Filtering and having a composite rowkey will help a little, but at the end of the day HBase still has to read every row, unless you physically separate via column families.

Comment: So, in the another option? total 1000+ different columns for table, but each row has maximum 30 different row. Does this option useful?

Comment: Everything would still need scanning, so it won't make much difference. You should go for a composite key and accept it won't be as fast as it could be.

Comment: Thank you so much!